# CakePHP load javascript components when needed

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP project that sometimes needs to load the Javascript and CSS for the jQuery Datepicker.

I only want it to load when needed, and I want one central loading point because there are several files involved, and if something changes, I, of course, don't want to go back and change it in all the places the datepicker files were loaded.

Right now, I've created an element called 'load_datepicker'. The only code in this file is the CakePHP calls to load the necessary files. I could not find any other solution.

This -seems- to be a good solution. I can load an element into any view or other elements.

Is this a reasonable way to approach this need or is there some specific CakePHP way to do this?

lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to include the javascript and css in your layout file, but surround it in an `if` block. Then in your controller actions, you can set a variable on the pages where you need the datepicker, and check for it in the if block.

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting idea. However, I tried it and it did not work. I set a variable in the element that needed to load the datepicker files. But, when the variable is set to load, it is not present in the layout file. I did the test after '<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>'. It seems by this point, the variable should be present.

Comment: I just realized I didn't mention that, int this case, the load_datepicker element was being loaded by another element. This other element is still being loaded and it is in this element that I am setting the flag to load the datepicker files.

Comment: I see now that you also said in my 'controller actions'. I put it there and it works. However, I would like to find a way to set it in the element or view that needs it. Any suggestions on making that happen?

Comment: well the element or view has access to all the variables that were set in the controller action. I usually just do something like this: `<? if(!empty($datepicker)) { ?> //code for loading js and css <? } ?>`

Comment: Thanks. What I was trying to get at is that with the solution you suggested, I cannot set the variable in the element that needs to use the datepicker. It seems I can only set it in the controller. Which is doable. Just not my first choice of places to be able to.

Comment: well you can also pass variables to an element when you render it in the `$this->Element()` function. (which version of cake are you using by the way? it's different in older versions)

Comment: Hello. I think maybe I am not being clear. I would like for the element to set the flag $load_datepicker. However, when I try that, the variable $load_datepicker is not present in the layout. I'm not sure why. It seems that variables created in an element should be visible in the layout. I'm not sure what version of Cake. But it is probably the most recent major release.

Comment: This solution seems quite backwards.  Why would you force your code to be in 2 places.  If you do it this way, and you want to add your element you have to 1) add your element, and 2) create some if() code.  Just put the JS call in your element, and DONE... that's it, nothing else.

Comment: The way I suggested in my answer doesn't use elements at all. just setting a variable in each controller action requiring a datepicker, and a simple if block in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Completely fine and a good solution for your needs.